# About JDBC Connection

Tags: java

A very simple question but i'm newbie in Java. How can I do the connection with my SQL Server DataBase that are in my network ?

I made the download of the JDBC 4.0, associate the file in my project and I'm trying the follow code, but I don't know how can I do a reference to my database

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        String connectionUrl = "what i put here ?";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "sa", "testtest");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378672%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://url.com;database=dbname;user=username;password=test")
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

replace the url/username/password. This is the connectionstring for sql server

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String db = "yourDB";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String user = "root";
String pass = "";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Have you though that MySQL and SQL Server could have a different connection string? Because Oracle connection string is different.

Comment: Oh, I though that by SQL he meant MySQL (as it is the most used). I didn't read it correctly. Sorry for the missunderstanding.